# Какую locale кодировку в linux лучше юзать с большими текстовыми файлами *.txt или *.lst?

Tags: linux, кодировка, utf-8, locale, ascii

Linux, Ubuntu в частности. Интересует вопрос, какую `$ locale` по умолчанию поставить и в какой кодировке лучше распознаются текстовые файлы, если например они с иероглифами (китайские, японские), кириллица, прочие языки (не инглишь).
Какую локаль выбрать, если основные массивы на английском, но так же чтобы распознавались с иероглифами и прочими разными языками?
`en_US.UTF-8 UTF-8` ?
Или надо `ASCII` ? Другую?
Что выбрать из `$ cat /etc/locale.gen` ?
Посоветуйте плиз, чтобы не маяться потом с перекодировками.
Поставил русифицированную Ubuntu с `LANG=ru_RU.UTF-8` , но что-то мне подсказывает, что это не лучший выбор.
Какое лучше расширение для создаваемых объемных текстовых файлов (или большим кол-вом размерами поменьше) выбрать?
*.txt или *.lst ? (При создании прогой crunch массива разницы не заметил, но специально время не замерял.)
С графическими оболочками текстовых прог не работаю, работа из терминала, 
сенкс.

Comment: *но что-то мне подсказывает, что это не лучший выбор* — ваш внутренний голос промахнулся. но если вас не устраивает русифицированный интерфейс, в любой момент вы можете выбрать любой другой язык. это не повлияет ни на что кроме языка интерфейса. кодировку, главное, не меняйте, и будет вам счастье.

Comment: По поводу кодировок: кто юзает НЕ UTF-8 - должен страдать в адском пламени.

Answer (score 2):

> Какую локаль выбрать, если основные массивы на английском, но так же чтобы распознавались с иероглифами и прочими разными языками?

в posix-совместимых операционных системах *локаль* состоит из трёх компонентов ­— языка интерфейса, региональных настроек и кодировки символов. язык интерфейса и региональные настройки можете выбирать по вкусу и настроению (для каждого отдельного процесса с помощью переменной окружения можно указать при его запуске какую-нибудь из поддерживаемых системой локалей, ведь локаль — это *свойство процесса*), разница будет **только** в сообщениях, формируемых процессом. а вот кодировку символов лучше оставить как есть — `UTF-8`. это нынче «стандарт де-факто».

> Какое лучше расширение для создаваемых объемных текстовых файлов (или большим кол-вом размерами поменьше) выбрать?

предполагаю, что под словом «расширение» вы подразумеваете не какую-то эзотречискую сущность (по аналогии с «расширением сознания»), а всего лишь суффикс в **имени** файла. так имя файла в posix-совместимых операционных системах не может оказать и не оказывает никакого влияния на программы, работающие с этим файлом. как хотите, так файл и называйте (в пределах возможностей файловой системы, в которой он хранится).

Comment: В чем же разница между расширением файла *.txt и *.lst ? Если никакой, то зачем собственно *.lst если был *.txt ? Может с каким-то определенным все же работает быстрее? быстрее записывает в него или быстрее открывает? или вообще никакой разницы?

Comment: я не знаю, что вы подразумеваете под термином «расширение файла». **имя** файла не может оказать никакого влияния на процесс, осуществляющий чтение и/или запись этого файла. ну, разве что разработчики той программы, которую вы запустите, решат таким образом извратиться.

Comment: под разницей в расширении я имею ввиду text.txt vs text.lst (пардон, не знаю как сие правильно именуется в линуксе)

Comment: да, это разные **имена** файлов. так же как, например, `blabla` и `pifpaf`. значение имеет не имя, а содержимое.